# Why is this logging more than 1 number?

Tags: javascript

I hope it's ok to post basic problems here!  I'm a student being asked to create a function to calculate an average.  Can anyone tell me why this is producing 3 numbers rather than just the average?
It returns 1, 19, 23 (23 being the average I'm looking for).

Thanks in advance for your help!

```js
var numbers = [3, 54, 21]

function getAverage() {
    var sum = 0
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    sum += numbers[i];
    avNumber = sum / numbers.length;
    console.log(avNumber)
    }
}
getAverage();
```

Comment: Correct your indentation. It aids in readability. Hopefully you will see the problem.

Comment: Because you have the `console.log` inside the `for` loop. In the snippet editor, there is a Tidy button. Click that to fix your indentation.

Comment: you just need the `sum += numbers[i];` inside of the `for` loop

Comment: @Samathingamajig It is inside the for loop?

Comment: As in it is the **only** thing that needs to be in the `for` loop. `avNumber = sum / numbers.length; console.log(avNumber)` doesn't need to be in the for loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go!

```js
var numbers = [3, 54, 21]
var sum = 0;
function getAverage() {
    for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    sum += numbers[i];
    
    }
avNumber = sum / numbers.length;
console.log(avNumber);
}
getAverage();
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: If this helped mark it as accepted and leave an upvote. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry- I'm new to this.  How do I do that?

Comment: On the left side of my answer, there will be an option of accepting the answer as most accurate and also there you can give an upvote by clickig the up-arrow